# What are underscored symbols in a VB DLL?

Tags: c++, dll, com, vb6

I have a C++ app in VS2005 and import a VB DLL. IntelliSense shows me all the symbols in the DLL as expected but it also shows all (or nearly all) of them again with an underscore prefix (no @s in them though). Why is this? What are the differences between the underscored items and the normal items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking VB6, the leading underscore version _Klass is the Vb-generated default interface for the class Klass. This site has a nice explanation:
 http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040721.htm

Answer (score 0):

In (some) c# coding standards the underscore prefix denotes a private variable, that might explain it... is it VB or VB.Net?

Comment: Old school VB, not vb.net. I don't think it's a convention, since they don't appear written like that in the original VB.

Answer (score 0):

Are the symbols properties?  If so, these might just be the private variables backing the properties.

Comment: All symbols: structs, vars etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this wiki article on Name Mangling for an indepth look:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling